# Cannot plot the correct x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting the following data using ggplot2 in R.

```
dat<-structure(list(Month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), grp1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("(-Inf,2]", "(2,7]", "(7,14]", 
"(14, Inf]"), class = "factor"), n = c(71L, 59L, 36L, 10L, 55L, 
73L, 18L, 10L, 97L, 82L, 22L, 5L, 120L, 79L, 15L, 2L, 140L, 62L, 
15L, 174L, 60L, 11L, 188L, 71L, 2L, 183L, 53L, 2L, 211L, 50L, 
2L, 171L, 69L, 7L, 1L, 98L, 85L, 13L, 6L, 72L, 62L, 24L, 9L)), class    
= "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-43L))
```

Here's my script:

```
library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot(data=test,aes(Month, n, fill = grp1))
p<- p +  geom_col()
p <- p + theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"),
         plot.margin = margin(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5, "cm"),
         panel.border=element_rect(colour="black",fill=NA,size=1),
         axis.line.x=element_line(colour="black"),
         axis.line.y=element_line(colour="black"),
         axis.text=element_text(size=20,colour="black",family="sans"),
         axis.title=element_text(size=20,colour="black",family="sans"),
         legend.position = "right", legend.key = element_rect(fill = 'white'))
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,300),breaks=c(seq(0,300,50)), expand=c(0,0))
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(seq(1,12,1)),labels=c("JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"),expand=c(0,0))
p <- p + labs(x = "Month", y = "Number of Days")
```

Here's the output:

[image: Output Image]

Why is it that I cannot plot the x-axis values?

If I don't set the scale_x_discrete, the plot will look like this:

[image: Output image without scale_x_discrete]

Any ideas on how to solve this?

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the Month name along the xaxis, then you can add in `as.factor(Month)` to your ggplot script. Heres an example:-

```
p<-ggplot(data=dat,aes(as.factor(Month), n, fill = grp1))
p<- p +  geom_col()
p <- p + theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"),
               plot.margin = margin(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5, "cm"),
               panel.border=element_rect(colour="black",fill=NA,size=1),
               axis.line.x=element_line(colour="black"),
               axis.line.y=element_line(colour="black"),
               axis.text=element_text(size=20,colour="black",family="sans"),
               axis.title=element_text(size=20,colour="black",family="sans"),
               legend.position = "right", legend.key = element_rect(fill = 'white'))
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,300),breaks=c(seq(0,300,50)), expand=c(0,0))
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(seq(1,12,1)),labels=c("JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"),expand=c(0,0))
p <- p + labs(x = "Month", y = "Number of Days")
p
```

Which gives you this:-

[image]

Comment: thank you for this. One question though. Why it did not appear in the original plot. I am plotting another similar data (same format) but did not require the as.factor. Only in this case, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think ```scale_x_discrete``` is the problem because the x-axis labels disappear as soon as this is run. It's because the month is set to integer (same problem happens when it's numeric as well). If you convert this to factor then the xaxis labels are preserved when run ```scale_x_discrete```